# Retry mechanism in case mule endpoint is not availlable

Tags: mule

I have a use case where i read the message from a topic and deliver to ftp endpoint.
In case the ftp endpoint is not available i need to store the message in a store
so that it is not lost. Future message read from the topic shouldn't be processed.
until the endpoint becomes available, once the endpoint is available we process the first
message received followed by all the messages in the order that they are received. I am not
sure how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Use the `Until Successful` scope: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

  ```
  <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore"
                maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="60">
      <ftp:outbound-endpoint ... />
  </until-successful>
  ```

  with an `objectStore` that preserves ordering. I don't think any of the default implementations guarantee that so you'd have to create your own.
- Store messages in a JMS queue and have a flow that consumes the messages transactionally and attempt the FTP dispatch. In case of failure, the transaction will fail and the message will be pushed back to the queue for a redelivery attempt. Make sure to use a JMS broker that supports message ordering (like with http://marcelojabali.blogspot.ca/2011/11/preserving-message-order-with-apache.html).

Comment: Thanks David so when we read from the object store will the order be maintained

Comment: Reviewed my answer accordingly.

Comment: David would it be ok to use a database store can I use until succesful scope with a db store.So until the endpoint is available I use a db store.The moment the endpoint is available I process the messages from the databasein a FIFO basis

Comment: Sure, there's http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/transport/jdbc/store/JdbcObjectStore.html you can extend to make it implement `ListableObjectStore` (required by `until-successful`). The trick will be to use an ORDER clause in the `allKeys` implementation that satisfies your FIFO requirement.

Comment: Can you gimme some pointers to Mule examples which will help me understand this.Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Mule examples"? Extend the existing `JdbcObjectStore` to make it implement `ListableObjectStore`, that's just Java/JDBC stuff.

Comment: Sorry i was not able to explain clearly .I have edited my post and added a code snippet, i was not sure on how to implement the allKeys.

Comment: Mmmh, mutating your original question like that is not great because part of my answer (JMS) doesn't make sense anymore. This is bad practice because future readers of this thread won't understand it.

Comment: Check how `JdbcObjectStore` implements the core operations and follow the same pattern (getter for the select all query, then use it in `allKeys`).

Comment: I see the following two methods in the JDBCObjectStore implementation that calls getter for the select all query

**public T retrieve(Serializable key)** throws ObjectStoreException {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) this.query(this.getSelectQuery(), this.arrayHandler, key);
  .......}
 AND
 **public boolean contains(Serializable key)** throws ObjectStoreException {
        this.notNullKey(key);
        Object[] result = (Object[]) this.query(this.getSelectQuery(), this.arrayHandler, key);
   .......}
No other method call in JDBCObjectStore calls  retrieves all Keys in the Object Store.

Comment: No, that's the right place :) You actually need to implement the method that retrieves all the keys, and then configure the related query so it uses the order you want to guarantee FIFO.

Comment: Sorry on mutating the original question.You are right the second option that you suggested wont make any sense. Since I started discussing on the first option.I have edited my post